# I2C Device Address Changing and Retention - VL53L0X

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am currently working with VL53L0X Time of Flight sensor and wanted to ask that whether the device retains the new address after it has been changed upon powering it off. Till now I have not been able to find proof in the data sheets or maybe I am skipping something.

Comment: I haven't found something about it being stored either. Probably you have to do it on every start as outlined in their ["Using multiple VL53L0X"](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/0e/0a/96/1b/82/19/4f/c2/DM00280486/files/DM00280486.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00280486.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### **I2C Address needs to be written every time after powering up.**

here is the snapshot from the manual from ST pointing the fact.

[image]
Document reference:
[AN4846
Application note](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/0e/0a/96/1b/82/19/4f/c2/DM00280486/files/DM00280486.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00280486.pdf)

From Section 2.2

> – define, “N” the number of VL53L0X (Struct MyVL53L0xDev_t
> BoardDevs[N])
> – Put all devices under reset
> – Enable VL53L0X one after
> the other and set their I2C address through  VL53L0X_SetDeviceAddress
> (&BoardDevs[i], FinalI2cAddr)

From [adafruit](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-vl53l0x-micro-lidar-distance-sensor-breakout.pdf) application note:
[image]

Comment: +1 Nice detective work.